# MySql - Combine data from three tables into one table

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I have 3 tables for data of divisions, districts and police_stations table. The table data are dependent like

```
divisions
- districts
 -- police_stations
```

Table format are

```
divisions
  id
  name

districts
  id
  division_id
  name

police_stations
  id
  division_id
  district_id
  name
```

Can I design just one table with all of my tables data with current table dependency? If I can, how will be the traversing  process?

Answer (score 1):

To group multiple tables together, you should use JOINS. This is a better database practice than creating new tables.

> The INNER JOIN keyword selects all rows from both tables as long as there is a match between the columns in both tables.

```
SELECT *
FROM divisions divis
INNER JOIN districts dis 
ON dis.division_id = divis.id
INNER JOIN police_stations pol
ON pol.district_id = dis.id
```

Note: Apparently the `DIV` keyword is reserved in mysql, so you you have to use something else to identify divisions.

If you insist on creating a new table with this data, you can use the `CREATE TABLE AS` recipe.

In order to do this though, we need to modify our original schema. New tables cannot have duplicate names, so we have to change the original tables to all have unique columns.

For example `name` becomes `district_name`.

```
CREATE TABLE combined AS (
  SELECT divis.id, divis.division_name, dis.district_name, pol.police_name
  FROM divisions divis
  LEFT JOIN districts dis
  ON divis.id = dis.division_id
  LEFT JOIN police_stations pol
  ON pol.district_id = dis.id
);
```

Here is a fiddle to demonstrate it

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7ec3b/1/0

This is really bad database design though. My first solution is recommended

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I am not asking about the query. I wanna how to design just one table with all data and where I can get my specific data with current dependency.

Comment: I added a solution for that. But know that this is terrible database design. Using joins would be much preffered

Answer (score 1):

Using a single table:  There would be an `id` for uniquely identifying each row; it would be the `PRIMARY KEY`.  There would be a `parent_id` to say which other row is its 'parent' (division is parent of district, etc).

The `JOIN` becomes a `self join`.

```
SELECT ...
    FROM tbl AS division
    JOIN tbl AS district ON division.id = district.parent_id
    JOIN tbl AS station  ON district.id = station.parent_id
    WHERE ...
```

Be sure to 'qualify' each field in the `SELECT` and `WHERE` with the appropriate 'alias'; example: `division.name`.

This design pattern works for most 'hierarchical' structures of arbitrary depth.  Yours is exactly 3 levels deep, so it is somewhat simpler.

Note that the `parent_id` would be `0` for any "district" rows.  And it would be useful to have `INDEX(parent_id)`.

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully it solves your problem

```
 SELECT * from divisions d
          join police_stations ps on d.id=ps.division_id
          join districts dist on ps.district_id =dist.id;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am not asking about query, please see my expectations in the comment section of @Richard Hamilton